# Selenium C# same id element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriverwait

So I've been stuck with this for some time now. I have an element `id=nextButton`. I need to be able to click it several times. The process looks like this:

Page1 -> nextButton.click() -> Page2 -> nextButton.click() -> ...

my not working solution for this was:

Page1

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
IWebElement nextButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"nextButton\"]"));
nextButton.Click();
```

Page2

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
IWebElement nextButton2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"nextButton\"]"));
nextButton2.Click();
```

Its no working.. It loads the Page1 than clicks the `nextButton` than new page shows up and it stops..
Please help :)

Comment: Can you show us ALL your code including the link to the page you working on?

Comment: If the page reloads you might get stale element exception when trying to click element again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to put some delay after clicking the `nextButton` to make the first page starting loading the second page, then to wait for the `nextButton` to be clickable on the second page and only then to click it.
What happens in your flow is: you trying to click the `nextButton` immediately after the previous click, while you still on the first page.
This code should work for you:

```cs
using WaitHelpers = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

wait.Until(WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='nextButton']")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(500)
wait.Until(WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='nextButton']")).Click();
```